# How to insert text to a (worksheet) textbox using VBA in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have inserted a text box in my worksheet, using the menu "Insert/Text Box" at the ribbon of Excel 2007. It has automatically been named as "TextBox 17".
I am trying to set its value using my VBA code, but I can't figure out the way to do it. I even tried to run a single-line routine just to feed the textbox with some text (like the following and other combinations) but failed.

```
Sub test()
    Sheets(1).Shapes.item(14).Text = "eventually some text"
    Sheets(1).Shapes(14).Text = "eventually some text"
    Worksheets(1).Shapes(14).Value = "eventually some text"
    Sheets(1).Shapes("TextBox 17").Text = "eventually some text"
    Sheets(1).Shapes("TextBox 17").ControlFormat.Value = "eventually some text"
    Worksheets(1).Shapes(14).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "eventually some text"
End Sub
```

While in research about this, I found answers only about activeX textboxes. But as far as I understood, the textbox I have inserted is not of this kind.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be working with no problem:

```
Sheets(1).Shapes(14).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "xxx"
```

Comment: object doesn't support this method or property error, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to set the text box contents with

```
Sub test()
    Sheets(1).Shapes.Item(14).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "eventually some text"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the text in a cell (maybe the one obscured by the text box) and set the text box value to the content of the cell (=$B$7).  The cell's text color can be changed to white to hide it, too.

The drawback is that it's vulnerable to a user changing it manually.